# How to "grab" matching files from a lookup file in bash?

Tags: shell-script, rename, filenames

I have a lookup file containing filenames. I also have a directory containing files, some of which have the names that correspond to some of the names in the directory.

How can I:

1. Move exact matching files to a new directory or
2. Remove non-matching files from the existing directory

Also, how can I do this recursively through a top-level directory and its subdirectories?

Comment: Is this tagged bash for any specific reason or it was actually meant to be "shell script"?

Comment: I lack the time to make a more appropriate answer right now, but I suppose you could use bash's globstar for each entry in the file (`for x in $(cat list); do ls **/$x; done`), although you'd have to test each name in the expansion of **/$x to rule out directories, or give the names to `find` and have it move the matches with `mv`, the problem is, if you have more than one match for the same name, how would you handle (1.)?

Comment: I don't expect there to be more than one match but it's certainly worth considering. I suppose, only one should be kept (the first one found perhaps) since I think we can assume that the content is the same if the filenames are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something along the following lines:

> `sed -e 's;^.*$;\^&\$; list-of-names > list-of-patterns`
>
> `rm $(find . -type f | grep -v -f list-of-patterns)`

Be careful, this will surely break if the filenames contain spaces or characters that the shell considers special. Please check what this would delete before running it for real!

(There might be a way of sidestepping the pattern file, but off the top of my head I don't see it).

Comment: safer way: 1) move the matching files in their new destination 2) delete the remaining (after user confirmation to proceed)

Comment: Right. But then you have to munge the paths, and that is more complicated than just finding out the files to delete. In any case, **do not do this unless you know what is going to happen**, and consider backing up the full original just in case.

Comment: another thing: your find will display names as : ./name1  ./name2 ./subdir/name3  and you are trying to match it to '^somename$' : it won't work. Maybe in that case recreate `list-of-patterns` to be : `^.*/&$` instead of `^&$`

Comment: @OlivierDulac, Brain fart. Need `\<` and `\>` instead of `^` and `$`. Thanks!

Comment: I really recommend the way I put it, as otherwise if a subdir match one of the filename, you end up deleting all that subdir's content... iow 'careful with that axe, eugene' (replace axe with rm ^^ it's a ZZtop song)

Answer (score 1):

The following bash script (warning: untested!) moves files from under `/directory/with/the/files` to under `/matched/files`. Only files whose name (sans directory) is in `/path/to/lookup.file` are moved. Beware that if there are symbolic links to directories in `/directory/with/the/files`, they are traversed recursively as if they were directories themselves.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
set -f; IFS=$'\n'
typeset -A filenames
for x in $(cat /path/to/lookup.file); do filenames[$x]=1; done
set +f; unset IFS
cd /directory/with/the/files
for x in ./**; do
  if [[ -d "$x/." ]]; then
    : # skip directories and symbolic links to directories
  elif [[ -n ${filenames[${x##*/}]} ]]; then
    # the file is matched, move it under /matched/files
    mkdir -p "/matched/files/${x%/*}"
    mv "$x" "/matched/files/$x"
  else
    # the file isn't matched
    :
  fi
done
```

Explanations:

- `shopt -s globstar` enables the [`**` glob](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-shopt) to traverse directories recursively.
- `set -f; IFS=$'\n'` turns off globbing and sets newlines as the sole word delimiter, so that the unquoted command substitution `$(cat /path/to/lookup/files)` is split at newlines only.
- `filenames` is an [associative array](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays).
- `for x in ./**` takes care that `$x` always contains a directory part (this way `${x%/*}` is the directory part of `$x`, with `.` for the toplevel directory), and does not begin with `-` (so it doesn't risk being treated as an option).
- `${x##*/}` expands to the filename part of `$x`, i.e. `$x` without the directory part.

Comment: Thanks. when I save this as a shell script, I get `fileextractor.sh: 1: fileextractor.sh: shopt: not found
fileextractor.sh: 3: fileextractor.sh: typeset: not found
fileextractor.sh: 4: fileextractor.sh: Syntax error: "fi" unexpected (expecting "done")`

Comment: @user31333 That's a bash script, you need to run it with bash (start with a `#!/bin/bash` line).

Comment: Yep I did that, and I run it like this `sh ./fileextractor.sh` from the script's directory. Still get the output above though???

Comment: Ok it runs now. However, I get `./fileextractor.sh: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'`

Comment: @user31333 If you don't have anything to do in the `else` part, either add a `:` (no-op command) or remove `else`.

Comment: Thanks that worked but now I'm getting `syntax error: unexpected end of file`.

Comment: @user31333 I've fixed another typo (I had a `fi` instead of `done` on the first loop).

Comment: quick question, why is there a trailing `/.` in the directory check `-d "$x/."`rather than `-d "$x"`?

Comment: @ChandraRavoori `[[ -d $x ]]` is true only if `$x` is a directory. `[[ -d $x/. ]]` is also true if `$x` is a symbolic link to a directory.

Comment: ah...that's interesting. +1 for an excellent solution